# Beetle ble with SD card reader

Tags: sd-card, bluno

I just started working on a project involving bluno beetle ble. For now, i'm sending the data from beetle to a android app i made.

But, for a fail safe mechanism in case the mobile is not in range or has disconnected from the device, i want to add a SD card reader to the device so i can save the data.

Is it really possible to add SD card reader to beetle ble? If yes, can someone provide any hint on what connections need to be made?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found an answer to this?

Comment: @RichardWinter check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I got it working. The connections that i made are as follows:

- SDA pin on beetle -> SDA pin on SD card module
- SCL pin on beetle -> SCL pin on SD card module
- GND pin on beetle -> GND pin on SD card module
- VCC pin on beetle -> VIN pin on SD card module

Then upload the sample code present on arduino IDE, or you can find it here as well: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ReadWrite

There we go!

EDIT: The soldering is tricky for bluno beetle. Detailed instructions can be found [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Bluno-beetle-breadboard-breakout/) :